# SQLFluff parsing error for hive alter table command

Tags: parsing, hive, lint, sqlfluff

I have created a hive sql file wherein i added an alter table statement in the file. However when parsing it using sqlfluff is throwing an error -

ALTER TABLE {{ params.piracy_analytics_interm_schema }}.converted_table ADD COLUMNS (COL_1 STRING);

error:
Line 16, Position 94: Found unparsable section: '(COL_1 STRING)'